# How do I hook up my iPod with iTunes?

Tags: ipod, itunes

I have a Apple Ipod 30GB. I need to run it on Lubuntu 14.04 with full functionallity. Can I run iTunes on Lubuntu 14.04. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Well, The only way to use iTunes in Ubutnu is using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), but you will be alone if you try to use the USB capabilities since those patches are not included in the source and is highly likely that it would work either way. So, the most logical solution, look for a native media player that supports your iPod or use a virtual machine and install Windows + iTunes.